# how do i create a usable .py file after using pycparser

Tags: python, pycparser

I am able to successfully parse a c file containing a function i want to use in python. now i cannot figure how to either a) call said function or b) create a .py file with said function.

All i have is this mysterious "ast" object

Comment: `pycparser` does not convert C to Python; it simply parses C code and lets you analyze it.

Comment: really? I am not seeing the utility of that :( any suggestions for being able to call this c function from python?

Comment: You could use [Cython](http://www.cython.org/) or [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) to make a small wrapper for the C function you want to call.

Comment: You could also look into [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html).

Comment: "I am not seeing the utility of that" Well, possible applications are given in pycparser site. Often it is a good idea to **read the docs** and plan before building the **big thing**. Don't you agree?

Answer (score 1):

This is a large undertaking. pycparser only gives you the *front-end* of the compiler. The backend you'll have to implement yourself.

For an existing project that uses pycparser just for this purpose (calling C from Python), see [cffi](http://cffi.readthedocs.org/en/release-0.8/).